# How to write a period of time in formal writing?

Tags: grammar, time, dates

I'm working on my thesis and i want to ask whether these formats of dates are correct:

> 1_ IT lasts from the 8th to the 15th of December, 2019.

> 2_ From January 26th to Fabruary 2nd, 2020

I also want to know whether i can use the verb "lasts" ( present simple) when talking about these periods which were in the past?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Either of the formats might be acceptable, or neither, as what is acceptable is largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, identify a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in tis application. That said, no "formal" style will accept *December* in lowercase, and there should be a space after the comma after *December* as well.

Comment: Thank you. The comma and the lowercase of december was just a taping mistake.

Comment: Perhaps "1_ IT **was** from ..."

Comment: Look up 'historic present' here on ELU. But I think attempting to use it here, with no context and for an IT course (?), would be faintly ridiculous.